# Is there any ROS class have videos available?

Tags: ros, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I know about ROS video is only about [Workshop](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/PR2BetaTraining) or [CoTeSys](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/CoTeSys-ROS-School), that is great for anyone who want to learn more about ROS.

I want to know if there exist any formal class for ROS, it will be very great to deep understanding ROS, and contribute to it.

If no one exist,is anyone can create it?

Thank you very much~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12503/is-there-any-ros-class-have-videos-available?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several classes linked on this page. However, I'm not sure if there are videos for any of them.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Courses

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-08**:
This doesn't have any video useful. If yes, please tell me, and I want to learn more. thank you~